# Issue in editing buddy display name using smack api android

Tags: android, smack

Hi I am using smack api to build a chat application in android. I am displaying all my buddy list names in a page. I need to edit the buddy name of a particular buddy. When I long press a purticular buddy, I am displaying a new screen where there is an EditText to enter the new name and when an edit button is there. When I press the edit button I am calling the following button to edit the buddy name.

```
public boolean editName(String jid, String name) {
    try {
        RosterPacket packet = new RosterPacket();
        packet.setType(IQ.Type.SET);
        RosterPacket.Item item = new RosterPacket.Item(jid, name);
        packet.addRosterItem(item);
        connection.sendPacket(packet);
        return true;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then the edit page is closed and the buddy list is refreshed. But the new name is not reflected unless i relogin to the application.

I am loading the buddy list using the following code:

```
public static Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
    Log.i("XMPPChat", "Name: " + entry.getName());
}
```

Can anybody tell me the reason?

Comment: Could be because of an roster bug in (a)Smack: https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/52429 Should be fixed in the latest aSmack snapshots.

Comment: @Flow Thank you...very much. That was a correct comment. I rectified it my adding a group name to all buddy name.